# Auto Sizing Wrap Panel in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, autoresize, wrappanel

I have a list of items (Bubbles) Size of the Items depends on the weight (Diameter of the bubble).

I am trying to add bubbles in a `WrapPanel`. I want that Wrap Panel should Wrap and will as Auto size item after its full.

**Full Capacity**
[image: Full Capacity]

**Element Added to Full Capacity**
[image: Element Added to Full Capacity]

## Xaml

```
    <ItemsControl VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Width="300" IsItemsHost="True" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.Items>
        <wrapPanelDemo:CircleUserControl CircleHeight="30" />
        <wrapPanelDemo:CircleUserControl />
        <wrapPanelDemo:CircleUserControl CircleHeight="50" />
        <wrapPanelDemo:CircleUserControl />
        <wrapPanelDemo:CircleUserControl CircleHeight="100" />
        <wrapPanelDemo:CircleUserControl />
        <wrapPanelDemo:CircleUserControl CircleHeight="200" />
        <wrapPanelDemo:CircleUserControl />
        <wrapPanelDemo:CircleUserControl />
        <wrapPanelDemo:CircleUserControl CircleHeight="250" />
        <wrapPanelDemo:CircleUserControl CircleHeight="100" />

    </ItemsControl.Items>
</ItemsControl>
```

**Also**

If there are more number of Panels (lets name them P1 and P2 containing bubbles) then Bubble (Weight 250 in P1) should look same as Bubble (Weight 250 in P2) even though P1 and P2 have different bubbles. (ratio of weight to size should be same
for all Bubbles in all Panels)

Comment: hmm.. so you want items inside panel to resize instead of the panel it self. Don't have idea for that at the moment. Also I can't see what have you tried to achieve that so far?

Answer (score 0):

What did you really mean by *auto size*? If you meant wrappanel should expand it's height, i think that already built in behavior of wrappanel. What limiting wrappanel's height is height of it's container. Try to put the wrappanel inside scrollviewer, and you'll get it keep expanding along with the content. And as wrappanel's height grows beyond available space, scroll bar will appears. Test example :

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <ItemsControl VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Width="100" IsItemsHost="True" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.Items>
                <Ellipse Height="30" Width="30" Fill="Green" />
                <Ellipse Height="50" Width="50" Fill="Green" />
                <Ellipse Height="100" Width="100" Fill="Green" />
                <Ellipse Height="100" Width="100" Fill="Green" />
            </ItemsControl.Items>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Result :
[image]

Comment: Auto-sizing means .... Panel will resize all items inside it to accommodate the newly added item.... and all items in the panel will always be visible (Scroll bar should not come as every item should be visible)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you put your wrap panel inside a StackPanel, then you should have the result you require